# How is it possible that if I have $2$ choices and $1$ of them is taken away, I have $0$ choices?

Tags: terminology, paradoxes

I'm a simple man living his life and enjoying mathematics. Today while thinking about choices I realized this paradox:

If I have $2$ choices and $1$ of them is taken away, I have $0$ choices.

How is that possible? Simple math shows I had $2$ choices, I took $1$ away, and I'm no longer left with any choices because there is nothing to choose...

Comment: I suppose there's no difference between 0 choices and 1 choice. (In fact, I'd argue that "0 choices" doesn't exist, since anything that looks like 0 choices is actually 1 choice. This point of view has the advantage that $2-1$ doesn't equal $0$.)

Comment: You don't have two choices, you have one choice of two options. You are using "choices" in two different ways - to count the ability to make a choice, and to count the options of a single choice.

Comment: hot dog/hamburger, but you don't like hot dogs

Comment: This question appeared today on the showerthoughts subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/3rvwyg/if_i_have_2_choices_and_1_of_them_is_taken_away_i/

Comment: This is a linguistic "paradox". Not a mathematical one.

Comment: I agree with @Asaf, even though I answered the question - this really isn't a math question. It is a question that shows the value in clearly defining terms, but it is probably best closed as off topic.

Answer (score 14):

You are abusing the word "choice," giving it two meanings.

You have one question (What to eat?) with two options (hot dog or hamburger.)

To be a "choice," a question has to have to have at least two options. So when you reduce the **options** by one, you no longer have any choices.

By applying the word "choice" to both the question ("What do I eat?") and the options ("burger," "hot dog") it is not actually surprising that reducing your choices/options from two to one reduces your choices/questions from one to zero.

You could make a dual "joke" with the same error, but in the other direction:

> Why is it that, when I start out with two choices, and I make one choice, I have no choices left?

Answer (score 1):

If you have $2$ balls, then there are $2$ ways to choose $1$ ball out of the $2$.

If you have $1$ ball, then there is $1$ way to choose $1$ ball out of the $1$.

These correspond to the *binomial coefficients* $\binom{2}{1}$ and $\binom{1}{1}$ respectively. This is how we think of the matter mathematically.